# Calling google maps API from wp8

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, windows-phone-8, webclient

So what I was trying to do is basically calling google maps webservice sending my longitude and latitude and I will get back as a result the details of my location. Like the street name and the address for example.

The code was initially working until it started to give an error message of "The remote server returned an error: NotFound".

So trying to solve this issue I made another simple which its only functionality is to send a request for google maps API as following

MainPage.xaml which consists only of a textblock and a button. The button will siimply send the request and the result will be printed in the text block. So I guess no need to show it here

c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetStreetName.Resources;

namespace GetStreetName
{
     public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
     {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(getStreet_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.480837,-0.190243&sensor=true"));

    }

    private void getStreet_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            streetLabel.Text = "Download cancelled.";
            return;
        }

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            streetLabel.Text = e.Error.Message;
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        streetLabel.Text = e.Result;

    }

    // Sample code for building a localized ApplicationBar
    //private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    //{
    //    // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
    //    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

    //    // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
    //    ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
    //    appBarButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
    //    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

    //    // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
    //    ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AppBarMenuItemText);
    //    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
    //}
 }
}
```

The longitude and latitude are just dummy values that lead to Chelsea FC Stadium.
Any way if you tried to use the same url in some sort of REST console it will work perfectly fine.

Any Suggestions ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible problem with `https`. Did you tried to use `http` instead `https` just for test?

Comment: Ops u got me on that :D. Absolutely correct, thanks :)

Comment: I hate WP for this issue! If you perform `phone reset` this can help to solve this issue. But I don't think that this is acceptable for you